# Display from duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, group-by

Consider there is a table which has 2 columns in it, *Name* and *Age*, 
and records like **User1, 21, User2 22, User1 22, User3 19, User3 20**.
As you can see the User1 and User3 has two values for Age, I only want to retrieve the records with ***last or maximum value of the Age***.

Comment: Hello  KaramjeetSingh01, welcome to Stack Overflow. `mysql` and `postgres` are two dfferent database products, plus tag only the one that you are using.

Comment: @GMB, my requirement can be fullfilled in mysql or postgresql that's why I added both tags.

Comment: Please, improve the readability of the example provided

Answer (score 1):

> I only want to retrieve the records with last or maximum value of the Age.

You can use simple aggregation for this:

```
select name, max(age) age from mytable group by name
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Can you please help me out further more; Lets consider same table but with one added column as "Job", now for the User1 which has two records, the values for Job are also two different values, and I want to retrieve the last value entered or Job which has the maximum age.